# How to integrate Postgres advisory lock functions into SELECT and UPDATE?

Tags: postgresql, locking, concurrency, postgresql-13

Using Postgres 13 in a Node.js application, I have a simple task to do:

- `SELECT` a row (identified by its primary key)
- Run some application code that cannot be done in the database* with that data.
- `UPDATE` the row.

**Edit**: Because of the stuff happening on application level and outside of the database, I cannot use a transaction.

The problem is: concurrency. I need to make sure that the data fetched in `SELECT` is still the same when the `UPDATE` happens for that very row. If another process changes the data in between, then the `UPDATE` gets messy. So, I need some kind of locking so that other processes need to wait/retry.

What kind of locking would I need here?

I think it's the advisory locking.

If so: How can I integrate those into my `SELECT` and `UPDATE` query?

My idea was something like

```
SELECT my_id, my_column FROM my_table WHERE my_id = $1 AND pg_try_advisory_lock(my_id);
```

(if that doesn't return anything, I do not proceed)

and

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_column = $2
WHERE my_id = $1 AND pg_advisory_unlock(my_id) IS TRUE 
RETURNING my_column;
```

However, that doesn't work. Concurrency seems still to happen. I don't know why. For reasons unknown to me, the `UPDATE` doesn't return anything sometimes if the condition `AND pg_advisory_unlock(my_id) IS TRUE` is present.

What am I missing here?

I found a ton of articles explaining the idea behind advisory locks but nothing on how to integrate them into your code. As you see, my statements have parameters. That's why I cannot use transactions. Using functions would also be problematic for some non-DB-related reasons. (Version control system doesn't like them.)

(*I know you guys like to challenge statements like "cannot be done in the database". But in my case, it's not only technical but also organizational reasons why this code needs to be executed on application level and cannot be done in the DB. So, for the sake of the question, please just accept it as a matter of fact.)

Comment: Hmm, why not just use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`?

Comment: That didn't work for me either in my first test. And I don't know how precisely it is supposed to work. How does Postgres know "who" did obtain the lock - by session id? What if in between, a network error happens and the clients needs to reconnect - will this `LOCK` stay forever?

Comment: The transaction that ran the `select for update` will hold the lock. And the lock will go away once your transaction commits (this assumes that everything **is** done in a single transaction)

Comment: No, **nothing** is done in a transaction. Between `SELECT` and `UPDATE` I am (and I have to) on application level.

Comment: "As you see, my statements have parameters. That's why I cannot use transactions."  This makes no sense.  How do you think parameters preclude transactions?

Comment: "No, nothing is done in a transaction"  On the contrary, almost everything is done in a transaction.  If you don't create them explicitly, they are created for you automatically.  You can't avoid transactions in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @jjanes
Ad 1: Well, if I try the simplest of all explicit transactions `BEGIN; SELECT $1 AS foo; COMMIT;` I keep getting `cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement`. Of course, a transaction consists of at least three statements. I don't know how to overcome that in the driver I have to use.
Ad 2: The point is that the things I do between `SELECT` and `UPDATE` are not done in a transaction and cannot be done in a transaction. It doesn't matter in this context whether Postgres wraps a simple `SELECT` in an implicit transaction or not.

Comment: Prepare three separate statements and call each in turn.  Although most drivers handle the BEGIN and COMMIT by other means, so you would really only prepare one in that example.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_column = $2
WHERE my_id = $1 AND pg_advisory_unlock(my_id) IS TRUE 
RETURNING my_column;
```

There's a race condition here. The lock is released when the UPDATE hasn't happened yet.

The lock should be released in a separate statement after the UPDATE.

Besides, in the Read Committed isolation level, which is the default mode, WHERE conditions can be evaluated several times (*) if the command has to wait for a row lock (independently of your advisory lock). Even if it's not clear that a row lock can exist in your particular case, it seems like a hazard that you should eliminate. Obviously having `pg_advisory_unlock(my_id)` being called a second time in the same statement wreaks havoc on the locking logic here.

(*) From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED) on Read Committed:

> The search condition of the command (the WHERE clause) is re-evaluated
> to see if the updated version of the row still matches the search
> condition

Comment: I see. But what if between the `UPDATE` and `pg_advisory_unlock` something unexpected happens in the sense of a connection loss or an application crash? I guess, in that case, the lock might remain forever. As mentioned, using a transaction would be inconvenient for me due to params.

Comment: @cis: the maximum lifetime of the lock is the session. When the session goes away, the lock goes away.